# Why in the same value in directive is defined and undefined at the same time?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Why I have value in scope as undefined but it is defined.

**HTML**

```
<body ng-app="plunker">
    <test-dir></test-dir>
</body>
```

And **JS**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.directive('testDir', function($log) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: 'My Dir',
    link: function(scope, element, arrts) {
      scope.test = scope.test || '2';
      $log.info(scope, scope.test);
    },
    scope: {
      test: "@test"
    }
  }
});
```

The strange that `$log` will show `scope.test` for `scope` undefined and `scope.test` for `scope.test` is 2?

[image]

I cannot understand!

http://plnkr.co/edit/EU3llFTQYTEFgpKA5Y2Q?p=preview

This is working if I use `test: "=?test"`. But I did not want double way binding and this is not the matter to make things works. This is matter of understanding why the same value shows different values in log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because there are 2 `$digest()` cycles during initializing directive.
In the first you create your variable `test` and set it to `'2'`. After `$digest()` works again and your variable sets to indefined (it's read from attribute).

You can observe that just simply making some small hack: wrap your `$log()` function by next way:

```
setTimeout(function () {$log.info(scope, scope.test)}, 0);
```

Now you will see in the console that your `test` variable is set to `undefined` both in the scope and in the simple log. `$log()` function will work right after `$digest()` will finish work.

You can make a small trick:

```
scope: {
  testA: "@test"
}
```

and in the `link` function:

```
scope.test = scope.testA || '2';
```

So you could see that your `test` variable will always be set to some value.

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/sywQKotOuX240VRYgz6Q?p=preview

Comment: Thank you. Although I am still do not understand absolutely the same moment the same value is different, depending on how you call it, anyway I understand it better now.

Comment: @Sergey Romanov : You are welcome. For more deep understanding the best practice is to read spurce code of `AngularJS`

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to pass something through to your isolated scope from your html like so:

```
<test-dir test="true"></test-dir>
```

Otherwise your isolated scope variable "test" is not defined, and every digest cycle will be set as undefined.

The problem is that you are telling AngularJS that something is being passed through from the parent scope to you directive's isolated scope via the code:

```
scope: {
    test: "@test"
}
```

Angular will continually try and match the value on your isolated scope with that of the parent.

You could remove the **test: "@test"** altogether, and the user can still update it, the value is not visible to any other scopes outside the directive's though.

BTW - @test will expect test to be a function on the parent scope - you probably want =test if you do want to pass something through..

Comment: What if I want something that if it is not defined, I set default value? I am creating custom component with will have hundred different attributes. And all of them will acualy have default values. I cannot require user to set at least `somethign="true"` for every attribute.

Comment: Then remove the value test="@test" from the isolated scope and just have scope: {} instead. Your original example should work as expected then.

Comment: Can you tell more? If I delete it from scope, then user cannot set it if he wants, right? And I edited topic. I know how to solve. The problem is not to make it work, but to understand why because to me, what I see is impossible.

Comment: > BTW - @test will expect test to be a function on the parent scope - you probably want =test if you do want to pass something through..

function would be `&test`